# Sourceforge SimpleXML Enum serialization

Tags: java, simple-framework

[SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) can serialize a Java Enum fine but when it comes to de-serialization, it returns null instead of creating Enum from the generated XML. Is it something I am doing wrong of Enum serialization is not supported at all?

Serialization returns this:

```
<TestStatus>
  <status>Functional</status>
</TestStatus>
```

Test Enum:

```
   @Root
    public enum TestStatus {

        AVAILABLE("Functional"),
        NOT_AVAILABLE("Dysfunctional");

        @Element
        private String status;

        private Status(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can quote XML as code - you don't have to add the ampersand characters

Comment: @Peter, sure will do that, Ta.

Comment: @Afridi I meant I had edited your text to show the XML...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML enum case-sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069903/simplexml-enum-case-sensitivity)

Comment: actually the answer is here, voting to close as dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069903/simplexml-enum-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 2):

How do you serialize your enum?

if you use it like this, it should work without problems but will return some different XML:

**Example:**

```
@Root
public class Example
{
    @Element
    private TestStatus status = TestStatus.AVAILABLE;

    // ...
}
```

**Test:**

```
final File f = new File("test.xml");

Serializer ser = new Persister();
ser.write(new Example(), f);

Example m = ser.read(Example.class, f);
```

**XML:**

```
<example>
   <status>AVAILABLE</status>
</example>
```

*You can rename the xml-tags with annotationarguments, but the value wont be changeable.*

---

Another (possible) solution is using a custom converter:

**Annotations of the enum:**

```
@Root()
@Convert(TestStatusConverter.class)
public enum TestStatus
{
    // ...
}
```

**Converter (Example)**

```
public class TestStatusConverter implements Converter<TestStatus>
{
    @Override
    public TestStatus read(InputNode node) throws Exception
    {
        final String value = node.getNext("status").getValue();

        // Decide what enum it is by its value
        for( TestStatus ts : TestStatus.values() )
        {
            if( ts.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(value) )
                return ts;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum available for " + value);
    }


    @Override
    public void write(OutputNode node, TestStatus value) throws Exception
    {
        // You can customize your xml here (example structure like your xml)
        OutputNode child = node.getChild("status");
        child.setValue(value.getStatus());
    }
}
```

**Test (enum):**

```
final File f = new File("test.xml");

// Note the new Strategy
Serializer ser = new Persister(new AnnotationStrategy());

ser.write(TestStatus.AVAILABLE, f);
TestStatus ts = ser.read(TestStatus.class, f);

System.out.println(ts);
```

**Test (class with enum):**

As above but with `AnnotationStrategy`

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to add annotations to enums, they serialize automatically.

Comment: Well, the question mentions that, the issue is with deserialization