# SimpleXML enum case-sensitivity

Tags: java, enums, new-operator, simple-framework

I have been trying to create an XML using the simplexml library (v2.6.2) 
http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php

The XML I want to create has to hold an enum value, which should be case-sensitive. Following is the POJO :

```
 package pojos;

public enum MyEnum {

    NEW("new"),
    OLD("old");

     private final String value;

     MyEnum(String v)
     {
         value = v;
     }

     public String value() {
            return value;
        }

        public static MyEnum fromValue(String v) {
            for (MyEnum c: MyEnum.values()) {
                if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
        }

}
```

Following is the serializer code :

```
import java.io.File;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import pojos.MyEnum;


public class TestEnum {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        MyEnum example = MyEnum.NEW;
        File result = new File("myenum.xml");

        serializer.write(example, result);

    }

}
```

The resultant output :

```
<myEnum>NEW</myEnum>
```

The desired output :

```
<myEnum>new</myEnum>
```

How should I proceed ? I cannot change the variable name in the enum as it happens to be the keyword "new" !

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some investigation of the source code, i have discovered that the library uses interface `Transform` to transform values to Strings. The default behavior of enum transformations is defined by class `EnumTransform`. In order to customize that, you can define you own Transform class. The following version of `Transform` implementation would call `toString()` instead of the default `name()` on the enum objects.

```
class MyEnumTransform implements Transform<Enum> {
    private final Class type;

    public MyEnumTransform(Class type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Enum read(String value) throws Exception {
        for (Object o : type.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (o.toString().equals(value)) {
                return (Enum) o;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String write(Enum value) throws Exception {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

`Transform` objects are returned from `match` method by objects of `Matcher` interface. There could be several `Matcher` objects. The library tries them one by one until it finds one that returns a non-null `Transformer` object. You can define your own `Matcher` object and pass it as argument to the constructor of `Persister` class. This object will get the highest priority.

```
Persister serializer = new Persister(new Matcher() {
    public Transform match(Class type) throws Exception {
        if (type.isEnum()) {
            return new MyEnumTransform(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
 });
```

Finally, you wont forget to define a toString method on your enum classes. Then the combination of codes above will do you the work of encoding enum objects using their toString values.

Comment: Tried this code :  public String toString()
  {
  return this.value.toLowerCase();
   
  }

Comment: Overriding as per the above code is not working, it still shows "NEW" rather than "new"

Comment: @zombie  i have revised my answer. i think this time it really does what you expect.

Comment: Last time I didnt try the code - now I can see that Matcher's match() cannot return custom Transform objects :(

Comment: @zombie I remember i tried the code and it ran perfectly well. So what do you mean by `cannot return custom Transform objects`? Is it compiling problem or something ?

Comment: Sorry, I wonder what was the issue. The error disappeared after cleaning up the project. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was trying to figure out how to do this with a Converter, but a Converter never gets access to the Class, so there's no way to get at the Enum class of the annotated member when reading from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `toString()`

```
@Override 
public String toString() {
       return this.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

Then write results using

```
serializer.write(example.toString(), result);
```

Comment: Try serializer.write(example.toString(), result);
I have updated the answer

Comment: Sorry I had to reopen the accepted answer. Just observed this changed my output XML tags : <string>new</string> I need the tags to be myEnum.

Comment: Oh.. I looked around. In the API, The serialization of enums uses the final name() method of enum. So, you will get the declared name in output only.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [serializer code](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start) and undestand what that is doing, as you have not annotated any of your fields...which (according to their docs) should throw an an exception.